# IE7 - margin: auto affecting sibling element

Tags: css, internet-explorer, margin, internet-explorer-7

Strange IE7 bug that I have no idea about...

Heres the HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class='header-overlay'>
        <div class='header-overlay-content'>
                 <ul>
                     <li>Contact Us</li>  
                     <li>FAQs</li>          
                 </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav"></div>
</header>
```

And the applicable CSS:

```
header {
    background: url('img/header-background.jpg') center no-repeat; 
    height: 325px;
    width:100%;
}

.header-overlay {
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.header-overlay-content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.nav {
    background: url('img/main-nav-blank.png') no-repeat;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 57px;
    position: relative;
    top: 235px;

    margin: 0 auto;   /* this causes problems! */   
 }
```

Basically, header-overlay is supposed to take up the full page width at the top (hence width: 100%) and nav is a bar that is horizontally centered a few hundred pixels below it. They have no relation other than being sibling elements in the header, but IE7 renders them like this:

[image]

header-overlay gets pushed the same amount that nav does - totally mystifying to me why this would happen, and it doesn't occur in any other browser, including IE8... help, please?!

Comment: I can't test it because I got no IE7 here but you can try setting top and left of the overlay to 0 (the absolute element)

Comment: yeah, that seemed to do the trick... _sigh_

Comment: For legacy IE it's always a pain, putting top and left is just safer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this css

```
.header-overlay {
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

The absolute div think it should start whee the content starts, and since the only content you have is the nav, so it got confused